# Using Azure function bot in VS2017 Workaround does not work

Tags: botframework

I try to debug a azure function bot with the article [Debug a Consumption plan C# Functions bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#debug-csharp-serverless=)

I use VS2017 and I don't get the `dotnet restore` working.

I downloaded the Bot code from the azure portal and downloaded the `.csproj` file from the article and put the unzip file into the messages folder.

When I run `dotnet restore`, I get:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.402\NuGet.targets(114,5): warning : Kein wiederherzustellendes Projekt gefunden! [C:\Use
rs\sschoof\Source\Repos\dgHelperFunction\Bot.sln]
```

(the german means: "no project to restore found"). I use VS2017 15.8.4 and dotnet cli 2.1.402.

How can I restore the packages for my functions bot?

See also https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/273

Comment: If you do not have a tangible and specific reason to be using a functions bot, I would highly recommend against functions bots.

Comment: @JasonSowers Thanks for your advice. I wanted to try functions bot to compare it to a regular bot. Can you give me some background information for your advise? I have a bot with only a few chats daily and thought that this may way way to host the bot at a very low price.

Comment: Functions bots were a rough way to get bots working in the early days of the Bot Framework, and as such aren't as 'fully' supported as the web app bots. Additionally, they are prone to strange errors that are buried in the azure service instead of in the bot framework where they can be easily debugged.